# XPath to Select Nodes Starting with a Certain Value

Tags: xpath

Given the XML structure

```
<Doc>
   <Other />
   <Q1 />
   <Q2 />
</Doc>
```

How can I select only nodes that begin with a "Q", e.g. /Doc/Q1 and /Doc/Q2?

It seems like this can be done with `starts-with`, but I have only found examples that apply `starts-with` to the value of the node

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`/Doc/*[starts-with(name(), 'Q')]`

Comment: note that you can use `local-name()` to omit namespaces in complex XML