# XPATH lookup up in nodes with a prefix

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have an XML like that:

```
<request type="POST">
<paths count="0"/>
<values count="9">
    <Invoices1>123ABC</Invoices1>
    <Invoices2>456EFG</Invoices2>
    <Invoices3>789HIJ</Invoices3>
    <Invoices4>012KLM</Invoices4>
    <case_Email>Email</case_Email>
    <case_Print>case_Print</case_Print>
    <case_Fax>Fax</case_Fax>
    <zone_TexteReponse>jkg</zone_TexteReponse>
    <Editer>Editer</Editer>
</values>
```

I would use XSL to transform this XML but I'm struggling with the tag Invoicexxx.
How can I select them with XPath:

```
/request/values/Invoices*
```

Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath to Select Nodes Starting with a Certain Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337341/xpath-to-select-nodes-starting-with-a-certain-value)

Comment: Another duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167369/xpath-query-for-node-names-matching-a-certain-pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
/request/values/*[starts-with(name(), 'Invoices')]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
/request/values/*[starts-with(name(), 'Invoices')]
```

This is a very good example of how *not* to use XML. Here is how this XML should look like:

```
<request type="POST">
    <paths />
    <values>
        <Invoice>123ABC</Invoice>
        <Invoice>456EFG</Invoice>
        <Invoice>789HIJ</Invoice>
        <Invoice>012KLM</Invoice>
        <case>
            <Email>Email</Email>
            <Print>Print</Print>
            <Fax>Fax</Fax>
        </case>
        <zone>
            <TexteReponse>jkg</TexteReponse>
        </zone>
        <Editer>Editer</Editer>
    </values>    
</request>
```

Now a much more sensible `/request/values/Invoice` would work.

Things to avoid with XML

- Element names with counters at the end. Things of the same type should have the same name. If the invoice ID is significant, make an ID attribute or sub-element. If you only want to express "this is the second invoice" then, well: It's the second `<Invoice>` right there in the XML.
- "Structured" element names. XML is itself structured. Don't make elements like `<case_Email>`.
- Attributes that store values that are self-evident from the XML structure. Stuff like `<values count="9">` is superfluous. If you want to count the children, count them. There is absolutely no need to *store* the count anywhere.

Comment: Ideally, the number would be in an attribute (assuming it's significant somehow).

Comment: Understand and fully agree.

Answer (score 1):

Use the path `/request/values/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'Invoices')]`.