# XPath query for all nodes which use a specific namespace prefix

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xaml, xpath-1.0

I have the following XAML (it may look odd since I've tried to remove redundant parts):

```
<Root xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:a="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Parent Name="SignIn">
        <a:List x:TypeArguments="InArgument(x:String)" Capacity="4" />
    </Parent>
    <a:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:Stringa, x:Object">
      <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">False</x:Boolean>
    </a:Dictionary>
</Root>
```

and I need an XPath query (limited to version 1.0, since .NET project) that returns **all** nodes (regardless of node's local name or location) which are using the `a:` namespace prefix.

> In the previous example the result should contain the nodes:
>
> `/Root/Parent/a:List`
>
> `/Root/a:Dictionary`

I've found answers how to search for *specific* node with *specific* prefix, but absolutely nothing to search **any** node with specific prefix.

The closest thing I could find has been the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144840/xpath-lookup-up-in-nodes-with-a-prefix) but it is not related to namespace prefixes.

Comment: Is it really the prefix you are concerned about, or is it the actual namespace? The common wisdom in XML is that you should allow people to use any prefix they like, and it's only the namespace URI that matters.

Comment: in my case it is only the prefix itself because I need to change it, both in the definition and also in the nodes where it is used. Long story-short: I'm writing an static XAML analyzer and already used `a:` for the default namespace. The problem is that I've received an XAML to analyze, which is also using `a:`. It will be too risky to change the existing logic, therefore I'm changing the name of the prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all elements in namespace `clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib`, you can write

```
//*[namespace-uri() = 'clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib']
```

If you really do want to search on the prefix (and most people would say this is bad practice), then you can do

```
//*[starts-with(name(), 'a:')]
```

which will probably work on most processors, even though XPath 1.0 doesn't guarantee it (it says *"Typically, this [the result of name()] will be the QName that occurred in the XML source. This need not be the case if there are namespace declarations in effect on the node that associate multiple prefixes with the same namespace."*)